# Listen to changes in multiple collections of mongodb using java and process the respective collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have say 100 collections, each with a different json structure . I want to listen all these ,say for example if there are changes in 4 collections, then i need to get new additions to these collections, process them parallely with their structure specific code .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Tailable Cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/). The mechanics are relatively simple, there are numerous oplog tailing examples out there written in Java, here are a few:

- [TailableCursorExample](https://github.com/deftlabs/mongodb-examples/blob/master/mongo-java-tailable-cursor-example/src/main/com/deftlabs/examples/mongo/TailableCursorExample.java)
- [Wordnik mongo-admin-utils](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-oss/blob/master/modules/mongo-admin-utils/README.md#comwordniksystemmongodbincrementalbackuputil)
- [OplogTailThread](https://github.com/reverb/wordnik-oss/blob/master/modules/mongo-admin-utils/src/main/java/com/wordnik/system/mongodb/OplogTailThread.java)